# Convert exponent number into nsnumber

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble converting a exponent number like 9.471347923322231e+18 into an nsnumber. Does anyone know how to do it the other way around? Thanks.

Comment: In which data type do you have it stored? NSString? double?

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

For exponential number you should use:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:12345
                                       exponent:-3
                                       isNegative:YES];
```

or if you want to get it from NSString:

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberWithString:(NSString *)numericString locale:(NSDictionary *)locale;
```

For example:

```
NSString *stringNumber = @"9.471347923322231e+18";
NSDictionary    *locale = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"." forKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:stringNumber locale:locale];
```